# Nuxt Fatal Error Error: [VuetifyLoaderPlugin Error] No matching rule for vue-loader found

Tags: build, nuxt.js

After running npm run build, I get an error: Error: [VuetifyLoaderPlugin Error] No matching rule for vue-loader found.Make sure there is at least one root-level rule that uses vue-loader and VuetifyLoaderPlugin is applied after VueLoaderPlugin.

package.json

```json
    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.27.3",
    "nuxt-mail": "^3.0.10",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.2",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
    "@nuxtjs/fontawesome": "^1.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Here is my config nuxt.config.js file:

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
import i18n from './config/i18n'

export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - client',
    title: 'client',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    [
      'nuxt-i18n',
      {
        vueI18nLoader: true,
        defaultLocale: 'hr',
         locales: [
          {
             code: 'en',
             name: 'Eng'
          },
          {
             code: 'hr',
             name: 'Hrv'
          }
        ],
        vueI18n: i18n
      }
    ],
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome'
  ],

  fontawesome: {
    icons: {
      solid: true,
      brands: true
    }
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    'nuxt-i18n',
    ['nuxt-mail', {
      message: {
        to: 'mislav0508@hotmail.com',
      },
      smtp: {
        host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
          user: "mislav0508@hotmail.com", 
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS, 
        },
        tls: {
          rejectUnauthorized:false
        }
      },
    }],
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {},

  i18n: {
    i18n: {
      locales: ['hr', 'en'],
      defaultLocale: 'hr',
      vueI18n: {
        fallbackLocale: 'hr',
        messages: {
          hr: {
            welcome: 'Dobrodošli'
          },
          en: {
            welcome: 'Welcome'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

I've tried installing vuetify-loader and vue-loader and adding them to the nuxt.config.js file. However after that I get another error:
TypeError: loaderContext.emitError is not a function

Please help.

Comment: There is an issue like this on Github, unfortunately this has nothing to do with your case IMO: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11346 Is it a fresh new project or do you have more packages installed here?